# ios DatePicker alternative or how to select multiple dates?

Tags: ios, ios6, datepicker

Ok, I have application with lists of to do tasks and I want to allow user to select due date for each task on a single screen. How would I go about doing this, datePicker seems just to big and clumsy. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what specifically do you not like about the datepicker? are there alternatives you've seen that you like?

Comment: I can't put ten date pickers on one view now can I.

Comment: You can put as much date pickers as you want into a view, at some time, when running out of memory, the OS will say: that was your last chat, guy.

Comment: Why don't you just make the user pick the due date when adding the task?